# Horizontal Calendar todays date highlight in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have been recently working on a mobile app, for which i have to code a calendar from scratch. i have to display the date in the scroll area which is in a parent div. i want the date to come in first, rather than hidden in the scroll area.
please help me out how can i pull today's date in the visible part of the browser

```
<div class="calendar">
<div class="scroll-dates">
 <ul>
   <li>Sun</li>
   <li>01</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Sun</li>
   <li>01</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Mon</li>
   <li>02</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Tue</li>
   <li>03</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Sun</li>
   <li>01</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Wed</li>
   <li>04</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Thu</li>
   <li>05</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Fri</li>
   <li>06</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>Sat</li>
   <li class="today">07</li>
 </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Write your version of jQuery, it's pretty straightforward!

Comment: @CallumLinington he has left a comment , in my answer . I dont get wat he is trying , do u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are [looking for. (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3p8Lghva/)

You can get the offset of the div you are looking for with offsetTop and move the parent div scroll position with scrollTop:

```
var offset = $("#container").find("div[day='"+today.toDateString()+"']")[0].offsetTop;
$("#container")[0].scrollTop = offset;
```

There is also an scrollLeft and offsetLeft. Be careful cause the offset is relative to the body element. (there is a property offsetParent).
To see the propertys in console, try:

```
console.dir($("#container")[0]);
```

Comment: how can i get the offset when my scroll is horizontal not vertical

Comment: i have another question is there any way i can code a touch scroll on my own from scratch. touch scroll for mobile touch for cross platform mobile app